# How to check for concurrent modification error while overriding Iterator for Linked List in Java?

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

I was trying to implement a doubly linked list in java and I am overriding the default Iterator interface , But how can I check for concurrent modification error inside my overridden Iterator?

```
@Override
public Iterator<T> iterator(){
        return new Iterator<T>() {
            private Node<T> trav = head;
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return trav!=null;
            }

            @Override
            public T next() {
                T data = trav.data;
                trav = trav.next;
                return data;
            }
        };
    }
```

This is my overridden Iterator interface.

Answer (score 0):

When implementing a custom iterator for a Linked List in Java, you can check for concurrent modification errors by using the `modCount` field of the `AbstractList` class, which is the parent class of the `LinkedList` class. This field tracks the number of structural modifications (additions, deletions, etc.) that have been made to the list. You can compare the value of `modCount` before and after iterating through the list to determine if any modifications have been made, and throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` if the values are different. Here is an example:

```
public class MyLinkedListIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {
  private final MyLinkedList<E> list;
  private int expectedModCount;
  private Node<E> current;

  public MyLinkedListIterator(MyLinkedList<E> list) {
    this.list = list;
    this.expectedModCount = list.modCount;
    this.current = list.first;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
    return current != null;
  }

  @Override
  public E next() {
    checkForConcurrentModification();
    E element = current.element;
    current = current.next;
    return element;
  }

  @Override
  public void remove() {
    checkForConcurrentModification();
    // implementation of remove() method goes here
  }

  private void checkForConcurrentModification() {
    if (list.modCount != expectedModCount) {
      throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
  }
}
```